# How do I prove this derivation of a definite integral?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

*Q,How to prove that*

**$\int_{0 }^{\Pi /2}\sin ^{m}x \cos ^{n}x  dx =\left [{(m-1)(m-3)(m-5)...2 or 1}\right ]\left [ \left ( n-1)\left ( n-3 \right )..2 or 1 \right ) \right ]\div \left [ \left ( m+n)(m+n-2) \right...2 or 1 ) \right ]$**

---

I tried integrating it by parts and came up with this:
$\int_{0 }^{\Pi /2}\sin ^{m}x \cos ^{n}x  dx =\frac{m-1}{n+1}\int_{0 }^{\Pi /2}\sin ^{m-2}x \cos ^{n+2}x$

And if I carry on integrating by parts,

$\int_{0 }^{\Pi /2}\sin ^{m}x \cos ^{n}x  dx =\frac{m-1}{n+1}\times\frac{m-3}{n+3}\int_{0 }^{\Pi /2}\sin ^{m-4}x \cos ^{n+4}x$

Finally,I will get

$\int_{0 }^{\Pi /2}\sin ^{m}x \cos ^{n}x  dx =\frac{m-1}{n+1}\times\frac{m-3}{n+3}...\frac{2}{m+n-2}\int_{0 }^{\Pi /2}\sin ^{1}x \cos ^{n+m-1}x$

---

I am unable to figure out the proof or even claim that my attempted integration is correct.Any help or hints are will be well appreciated.

Comment: There is a simple way i.e beta function

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki,Sir,what is a beta function?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html

Comment: What part of the proof are you unable to figure out? BTW, what you have written is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

set $u=\sin x$, we have
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}(u^2)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}(1-u^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}u\,du$$